# Calculate the difference between two DATETIME values in years

Tags: datetime, timestamp, timedelta, dolphindb

I’m wondering which DolphinDB function can calculate the time difference. For example, I have two values of DATETIME type, A and B. How can I calculate the time difference between A and B in years? The output should be like 0.5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract variable B from A and you can get the difference in seconds. Then divide the result by 365 * 86400 (which is the total number of seconds in a day) to obtain the yearly difference. For example:

```
(2022.10.18T12:00:00 - 2022.04.18T00:00:00) \ (365 * 86400 )
```

The result is 0.50274, meaning the difference between the two dates is 0.50274 years.